# DRY Principle: Angular2/Typescript and Java back end object duplication

Tags: java, angular, typescript, transpiler

I'm a Java developer but I've recently begun learning Angular2/Typescript. I've worked with Angular 1.x before so I'm not a complete noob :)

While working through a POC with a RESTful Spring Boot back end and Angular2 front end I noticed myself duplicating model objects on both sides a lot e.g.

Java Object

```
public class Car {
    private Double numSeats;
    private Double numDoors;
    .....
}
```

Now in interest of Typescript and being strongly typed I'd create a similar object within my front end project:

```
export interface PersonalDetailsVO {
    numSeats : number;
    numDoors : number;
}
```

I'm duplicating the work and constantly violating the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle here.

I'm wondering is there a better way of going about this. I was thinking about code generation tools like [jSweet](http://www.jsweet.org/writing-angular-2-applications-with-java/) but interested to hear if anyone else has come across the same issue and how they approached it.

Comment: It isn't about DRYness. The thing you're asking is writing an interface in two different languages - something that won't happen if you use pure JS. Tool recommendations are considered offtopic on SO, and this is something that should be done with a tool. If you're after Typescript, I'm quite sure there are not so many options, and you can google out them all, e.g. jSweet and https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator

Comment: Whether it should be done with a tool is a matter of opinion, which is the real point of the question as I see it.  People are always bending over backwards to shoehorn questions into the categories for closing, simply because it's not a question they like.  The fact that *your answer* would be to use a tool does not mean that a tool recommendation was requested.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys but I agree with @MarkAdelsberger the question isn't looking for a tool per say, it's more looking for opinions or use cases of how other people approached this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two schools of thought on whether this is a violation of the DRY principle.  If you're *really, really* sure that there's a natural mapping you would always apply to bind json in each language, then you could say that it is duplicate work; which is (at least part of) the thinking behind IDL-type languages in technologies like CORBA (but I'm showing my age).

OTOH maybe each system (the server, the client, an alternate client if anyone were to write one) should be free to independently define the internal representations of objects that is best suited to that system (given its language, what it plans to do, etc.).

In your example, the typescript certainly doesn't contain all of the information needed to define the Java "equivalent".  ('number' could map to a lot of things; and the typescript says nothing about access modifiers...)  Of course you can narrow that down by adopting conventions, but my point is it's not self-evident that there'd be a 1-to-1 mapping.

Maybe one language handles references more gracefully than another.  Maybe one can't deal with circular references but the other can.  Maybe one has reason to prefer a more flat view of the object.  Maybe a lot of things.

All of that said, it certainly is true that if you modify the json structure of an object, and you're maintaining each system's internal representation independently, then you likely have to make code changes in multiple places to accommodate that single underlying change.  And pragmatically, if that can be avoided it's a good thing.

So if you can come up with a code generator that processes the more expressive language's representation to create a representation for the less expressive language, and maybe at least use that by default, you may find it's not a bad thing for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... yes I think it's possible to do by transpiling the more expressive Java language into Typescript files. I'll update the question at a later date on my results.